# how to use handlebars from shell?

Tags: handlebars.js

I know how to use handlebars from java, but if I'd like to register some extensions, and compile some template to generate file with some testing data. `npm install -g handlebars` gives me some command to precompile templates, but I cannot find anything to evaluate that templates. I found only some very old unmaintained tool, but is there some correct way, up to date, official?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I still don't know if it's the OK way, but after a lot of search, I found `hbs-cli` tool(https://github.com/keithamus/hbs-cli). So usage could be

Install:

`npm install -g hbs-cli`

invocation:

`hbs --data <(echo '{"who":"world"}') <(echo 'Hello {{who}}!')  --stdout`